# Rearrange ranges of columns in a text file

Tags: ruby, perl, awk, sed, cut

I'm looking to rearrange some columns in a text file.

Basically I've got 32 columns and want 1-4,6-29,5,32

I can brute force this with awk, but that seems dumb. Any recommendations?

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer?In general, quick-draw selections can discourage other, possibly better answers, or even show the selected answer to be incorrect. Also, did it occur to you that others might still be preparing their answers?  There's no rush. Many here wait at least a couple of hours before making a selection.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Remember that it takes the earth 24 hours to rotate, and, because SO has people around the world contributing, it's very sensible to wait a day to select an answer. Grabbing the first one, or one in the first hour, can result in implementing an answer that isn't as good as one that will follow 23 hours later, since it can take a while to formulate an answer, test it, then write it up.

Comment: Please read "[ask]", "[mcve]", https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html. As is, your question is missing example input, example output, and your evidence of effort, such as code you wrote toward solving the problem.

Comment: You currently have accepted an answer that fully reflects the effort you have put into asking the question. It will not work for some input values, cannot be extended to work for other combinations of "columns", and is non-portable across UNIX installations. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a combination of `awk` and `cut` assuming the fields are separated by white space:

```
awk '{$30=$5;$31=$32}1' file | cut -d' ' -f5,32 --complement
```

For example:

```
$ seq 32 | paste -s | 
  awk '{$30=$5;$31=$32}1' | 
  cut -d' ' -f5,32 --complement

1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 5 32
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean each line of a file contains 32 characters, followed by a newline, and you wish to extract the strings for groups of adjacent columns given by:

```
column_groups = [1..4, 6..29, 5, 32]
```

Suppose you've read the input file into an array and

```
line = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEF\n"
  #     0        10        20        30 (offsets)
```

is one element of that array.

Then you can do this:

```
range_offsets = column_groups.map do |obj|
  case obj
  when Range
    obj.first-1..obj.last-1
  else
    obj-1..obj-1
  end
end
  #=> [0..3, 5..28, 4..4, 31..31]

arr = line.chars
  #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k",
  #    "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v",
  #    "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "\n"] 

range_offsets.map { |range| arr.values_at(*[*range]).join }
  #=> ["abcd", "fghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABC", "e", "F"]
```

If you wish to return a single string, tack another `join` to the end:

```
range_offsets.map { |range| arr.values_at(*[*range]).join }.join
  #=> "abcdfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCeF"
```

Comment: No, 32 columns, not 32 characters.

Comment: Text files do not have columns. That's why I assumed you mean characters. You need to edit your question to explain what each line in the file looks like.

Comment: @Will that's part of the problem with your question. 32 columns can and often does mean 32 characters - since you haven't posted a [mcve] even those few who do want to try to help you given how little effort you've put into asking the question are just guessing at what you want.